# REST naming conventions for representing children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following class model

```
class FooBar {
}

http://localhost:3000/foo_bars/
```

to access the above objects. Should I be using `/foobars or /foo_bars` to access the above objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `/foo_bars`. You'll have a controller called `FooBarsController` and a line that says  `resources :foo_bars` in your routes.rb file, and it will get a `/foo_bars` route.